# How to get rows with a value greater than the min value for that group plus a constant?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have some pageview data where each row is a single pageview and am looking to find pageviews from each user's *second* (and any subsequent) visit; for simplicity's sake I'll use a full day as the session length. I assume the query should look something like,

`SELECT date_time, url FROM pageviews WHERE date_time > date_add(min(date_time), 1)`

Of course, the min function doesn't actually exist, and I need the min date_time for each visitor, not over the whole table.

I looked at some other questions and it looks like the windowing and analytics functions may be the right thing to use, but the documentation is sparse and I can't find a single example of how to to this anywhere.

The following query

```
SELECT user_id, date_time, rank() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_time) FROM pageviews
```

returns a list of pageviews ranked by time, so I can technically take the one which is equal to 1 for each user_id, but I can't figure out how to do that. It doesn't seem to be possible to use the OVER clause inside a WHERE.

Sample data:

```
date_time                url                   user_id 
12-21-2015 00:00:07      www.mywebsite.com          1234
12-13-2015 14:12:02      www.mywebsite.com          5678
12-16-2015 23:24:25      www.mywebsite.com          5678
```

Desired result

```
user_id   
5678
```

(I need at least the user id; any extra info, e.g. the datetime of the second visit, would be great.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
 FROM  ( SELECT 
     user_id, 
     date_time,  
     rank()   OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_time) as rnk 
 FROM pageviews ) t  select user_id where rnk > 1;
```